# How to classify the recorded data from multiple sensors?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sampling

I'm tring to build a glove that will be able to recognize gestures by using arduino that is connected to flex sensors and an accelerometer (maybe also an emg sensor).

I am able to record all these data from the sensors that I read. What I want is to learn that how I can create a classifier to recognize those gestures. Some said to use Matlab or Pyton but I don't know where to start from. I saw some libraries for machine learning but I got lost immediately. I know just a little bit about the concept of sampling and classifing.

If possible I want some advice for sources that I can start to learn from.

*Note: I know java programming language mainly.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before applying machine learning to your problem, you may want to take some courses/tutorials on it.
[There](http://machinelearningmastery.com/best-machine-learning-resources-for-getting-started/) is a big list of ML materials.

And there are some steps, which may help you to solve your problem.

1. First of all, you have to choose suitable format for your data. To
   recognize gestures, you'll probably have to track how your
   parameters (flexion, acceleration) change in time.

   Еxample: you have your parameters recorded every 0.1s, and gesture
   length is 1s. So the feature vector will look like `[f0, f1, ...,
   f10, a0, ..., a10]`.
2. After that, you'll have to create **training set** - set of feature
   vectors with labels accordingly. At this point, you have to label
   gestures by yourself. You may need lots of examples to get your
   further classifier work.
3. The last part: choose some machine learning tool (I use Python with
   scikit-learn). There is a wide variety of classifiers, but i suggest
   using simple ones to start with (NearestNeighbors, Decision Tree).
   There are some Machine Learning libraries in Java, you can use them
   if you want. Use your training dataset to train your classifier, so 
   it'll be able to predict labels for new feature vectors.

Example (Python):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
# X is an array of feature vectors, y is an array of labels.
gestures = clf.predict(X_new)
# X_new is an array of feature vectors of 
# gestures you want to recognize
```

Also, you may find useful [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/grasp-and-lift-eeg-detection) Kaggle competition, it's also about hand motions recognition, but using EEG records.